# Terraform provider resource ID unique throw all resources

Tags: terraform

I am currently trying to create a resource for a terraform provider and couldn't find any information about ID uniqueness scope. I wonder, is it should be unique within the resource or every resources belongs to provider? Does anybody know?

Comment: Within the resource, because you assign it as a member of the struct. Please provide code if you want a more specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

The combination of resource type (`aws_instance`) and resource name (`web`)
must be unique inside one terraform module. Resources of different types can use the same name, as they use there own namespaces.

Example:

```
resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami           = "ami-a1b2c3d4"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
}
```

If resources have properties like `id` or `guid`, it depends on the API that the terraform provider uses how unique they have to be - this is resource type specific.

> The resource type and name together serve as an identifier for a given resource and so must be unique within a module.

from https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/resources/syntax

Comment: This is not the ID I am talking about. I mean the ID, that you have to set as a resource developer.